# Testing equality of betas of multiple assets in the Capital Asset Pricing Model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, finance

I am trying to understand how I can test whether the factor loadings (Beta) in CAPM for different stocks are statistically different between each other. I.e. I have 3 stocks with different CAPM betas. How can I test that those 3 betas are statistically different between each other?

Do you have an approach to do so and how do you justify that? I have been unable to find much in the literature.

Comment: I do not have time for writing a full answer, but here are some keywords for you. What you want amounts to testing the equality of slope coefficients in 3 simple regressions. Assuming i.i.d. errors, this can easily be done in the multivariate regression framework. The term [seemingly unrelated regressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seemingly_unrelated_regressions) (SUR) might be relevant. Assuming a more flexible structure of errors, this can still be done with some effort.

Comment: Later cross posted on [Economics SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/54614).